# How to make confirm box in JQGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid in which i have a column of buttons. I want to delete row from this button. My question is i want to make confirm message pop up when i click on the button. I appreciate if i can customize the dialog box. So how i can do this?
I have tried bootstrap pop up and query but i think i did something wrong.

```
So is there any way to make pop up in JQgrid?
```

This is my column.

```
{
                    name: "action",
                    align: "center",

                    sortable: false,
                    title: false,
                    fixed: true,
                    search: false,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                        var links = "<a title=''  href='/Admin/Workflow/Delete?id=" + rowObject.templateId + "'>" + "Delete" + "</a>";
                        return links;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Which version of JqGrid U r using?

Comment: set `modal = true` property of jqgrid. Else paste your compelte JQGRID code.

Comment: This link will be helpful. Please check - http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomDelMsg.htm